# open cv2 python multiply images

Tags: python, opencv

I have this simple code and I'm new at learning open cv2. This was supposed to do the chroma key efect but isn't working. Here's the code

```
import cv2

objectImage = cv2.imread("falcon.jpg")
background = cv2.imread("florest.jpg")
mask = cv2.imread("mask.png")

falcon = cv2.multiply(objectImage, mask)

back = cv2.multiply(background, (255 - mask))

result = cv2.add(falcon, back)

cv2.imshow("Image",result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyWindow("Image")
```

And here's the result:

[image]

And here is what it was supposed to look like:

[image]

Thanks to anyone in advance!

Comment: Can you provide us the original image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already made it I needed to divide by 255 to normalize the values

Comment: should be simpler to use bitwise_and in opencv itself :)

Answer (score 1):

A better alternative would be

```py
result = cv2.bitwise_and(image, mask)
```

---

For anyone who thinks that they are OK with

```py
result = (image/255.)*(mask/255)*255
```

just because it does generate a similar output. **Avoid it** as it does not involve OpenCV ensuring that the `image` and the `mask` are homogeneous (same shape and stride). When feeding the `result` as inputs to other OpenCV methods like `findContours()`, you are very likely to enter into *high-verbose* errors which only tell you that the image properties are not same (even though you think `.shape` for both `image` and `mask` outputs the same values.) Read more on [strides difference](https://answers.opencv.org/question/373/cv2-bindings-incompatible-with-numpydstack-function/) when the shape seems same.

Also, ensure that both `image` and `mask` possess the same datatype (use `mask.dtype`) before using the together.